# Change date format of multiple date columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a large dataframe with multiple date columns. I did like to use str.contains to identify all those date columns and change the format and retain the columns in original dataframe. Here is a sample of the dataset:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  SSN = c(204,401,101,666,777), 
  date_today=c("1914-01-01","2022-03-12","2021-07-09","1914-01-01","2022-04-05"), 
  date_adm = c("2020-03-11","2022-03-12","NA","2021-04-07","2022-04-05")
 
)
```

I have tried this code but looks like its very wrong

```
Data %>% mutate(select(contains("date")), as.Date, format="%d-%m-%Y")
```

End result is filter columns containing date then change format while retaining those date columns within the origina dataframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code uses `select` inside, instead, it should be `across`.  In addition, the `format` should be `"%Y-%m-%d"`

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
   mutate(across(contains("date"), as.Date, format = "%Y-%m-%d"))
```

-output

```
SSN date_today   date_adm
1 204 1914-01-01 2020-03-11
2 401 2022-03-12 2022-03-12
3 101 2021-07-09       <NA>
4 666 1914-01-01 2021-04-07
5 777 2022-04-05 2022-04-05
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `across` instead of `select`. Also you have to pass the right format, i.e. the year comes first in your data (but I wasn't sure about the order of the month and day in your data, so perhaps you have to change that.)

```r
library(dplyr)

dat %>% 
  mutate(across(contains("date"), as.Date, format="%Y-%d-%m"))
#>   SSN date_today   date_adm
#> 1 204 1914-01-01 2020-11-03
#> 2 401 2022-12-03 2022-12-03
#> 3 101 2021-09-07       <NA>
#> 4 666 1914-01-01 2021-07-04
#> 5 777 2022-05-04 2022-05-04
```

Comment: A difference of four seconds ... some questions get all the (rapid) attention :-)

Comment: @r2evans Yeah. And in that case it was a quick fix too. (: